# What is the license of MLKit and should I mention it in my app?

Tags: google-mlkit

If I'm going to use the Google MLKit in my app, should I put it's license in my app? And what is the license for DigitalInkrecognition?

Google's Terms & Privacy https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms doesn't have any mentions of this.